# Uncaught ReferenceError: CQ is not defined

Tags: aem

I am facing an issue in my  CQ  Environment. The page breaks with a ERROR in the browser console :"Uncaught ReferenceError: CQ is not defined" in the line below.Can you please give pointers.

The Error in Browser is below:
Uncaught ReferenceError: CQ is not defined;

Comment: Anybody could help how CQ load its client libraries?

Comment: Add more details what do you mean by build ? what code is been build ? what's the page you are trying to open ? Add a code snippet and error snippet.

Comment: Thank you @yashahuja The problem is the browser wasn't able to render the Components. For example the error is in the line,CQ.WCM.edit({"path":"/content/adaptive/theage/jcr:content/current-weather"..

Comment: To be more precise with the Error -- The Javascript object CQ is not recognized and the browser complains with an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: CQ is not defined; ".

Comment: Are you including the clientlibs in your page component ? If you are inheriting from foundation/components/page, then this is already available. But in case you are using creating your own page component from the scratch then make sure you have included clientlibs as shown here `<cq:includeClientLib categories="cq.widgets" />`

Answer (score 5):

When creating custom components see the comment above about adding

```
<cq:includeClientLib categories="cq.widgets"/>
```

Otherwise add a property like

```
dependencies    String[]    cq.widgets
```

to your clientlibs folder, as mentioned by https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-aem-multifield-components.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this page who is using Sightly rather than JSPs, this will be of use to you:

https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype/issues/1

You need to include the following in the page body:

```
<div data-sly-include="head.html" data-sly-unwrap></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but wanted to post this information in case it would be helpful to others.

I have the base version of AEM 6.0 and I kept getting the error "CQ is not defined" whenever I loaded the page. When I included the "Sidekick", then the error went away.

Comment: If this is the case, there is likely an older CQ /libs/foundation component (such as list) used on the page. The CQ library is not usually provided when editing using TouchUI

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your clientlibs folder

```
<cq:includeClientLib categories="cq.widgets"/
```

The classic UI throws an error as mentioned. You will not get this error in the touch UI. So edit the page in touch UI mode

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to my `customheaderlibs.html` for my site in CRXDE Lite and it fixed the issue
`<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='cq.widgets'}"/>`

[image]